# ESET NOD32 esets_daemon syslog flood

Tags: linux, daemon, syslog

On our computers with Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit Cinnamon, we have an antivirus solution from ESET, called NOD32 Antivirus for Linux. Current version is 4.0.82.0.

Problem is that the system log:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

Is being completely flooded by its main component:

```
/opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_daemon
```

With a repeating 3-line text:

> ```
> esets_daemon[PID]: warning[072d0000]: Not an absolute path:
> esets_daemon[PID]: warning[SOME-ID-CHANGING]: Not an absolute path:
> esets_daemon[PID]: summ[SOME-ID-CHANGING]: vdb=31400, agent=pac, name="", virus="", action="", info="Event occurred on a newly created file.", avstatus="not scanned", hop="accepted"
> ```

It floods the log within 3 hours with 242,920 lines!

As we all are on SSD drives, this could also lead to disks' faster wear off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reported this problem to ESET development team and their workaround is as follows, it is not an actual fix, I was told by ESET right now, that in the next build of NOD32 for Linux, this and much more issues will be fixed. It's only a workaround as pointed out by [Rui F Ribeiro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138261/rui-f-ribeiro).

```
sudo /opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_set --section global --set syslog_class
sudo /opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_set --section global --set syslog_facility=none
```

It works not only for the session, but it changes the antivirus daemon settings permanently.